# Changing the selector of a bar button item on touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navbar with a bar buttonitem on it. how would I go about changing the selector on the first press. I basically want to have the first press trigger the "showMenuView" selector and then while that's displayed change the barbuttonitem selector to be "hideMenuView"

here's the code I have so far:

```
 UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"globe.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showMenuView:)];
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set a new action.

```
[button setAction:@selector(hideMenuView:)];
```

But I think it would be a better practice to use a `toggleMenuView:` method, have a BOOL variable indicating wether or not your menu is visible and then hide or show it in toggleMenuView:

Answer (score 1):

You can call `setAction:`

```
[button setAction:@selector(hideMenuView)];
```